# Angular 4 TypeScript Says Property Doesn't Exist Even Though It Clearly Does

Tags: angular, class, typescript, types, compiler-errors

I have the following class in an Angular 4 project created from the Angular CLI:

[image: month-summary.ts]

I use it in the following method in the Home component:

[image: <code>*item*.monthId</code>]

Even though `monthId` is clearly a valid property of `MonthSummary`, the following error is thrown:

[image: <code>monthId does not exist on type 'MonthSummary'</code>]

This is incredibly strange because the following code *will* work:

[image: <code>*item*['monthId']</code>]

Is this the fault of the compiler? Is there something about TypeScript I don't understand? Am I missing something obvious?

I haven't been able to find anything like this on the web, and I don't know where to start debugging because this seems to be a compiler-related issue.

I also tried removing all of the type-enforcement from all of my code, but it had no effect.

Help?

EDIT: Per request, here is the definition of `getMonthly()`:

[image: <code>getMonthly()</code>]

I have replaced the URL for security reasons. I can confirm that this method works properly through the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools.

EDIT 2: `authHttpService` performs the mapping of the reponse to JSON with `res => res.json()`. It also handles adding an authorization header to requests.

Comment: you can put the definition of service .getMonthly?

Comment: Try change the forEach with .map and see that ocurre

Comment: @alehn96 I put up the definition of .getMonthly().

Comment: try change .map(res => resp.json());

Comment: @alehn96 Ah sorry, I should have explained that code better. authHttpService already does that.

Comment: are you using old `httpModule` or new `httpClient`? seems like you're not casting your service response to `MonthSummary[]`. you either need explicit cast (for old httpModule) or  `get<MonthSummary[]>(url)` for new `HttpClient`